# Telebot API Python3

Tags: python-3.x, telegram, telegram-bot

When i start this script in telegram. Script run correct but

```
            if message2.text.lower() == 'what do you do?':
                bot.send_message(message2.chat.id, 'im learning mode?  ' + message2.chat.first_name +
```

In this place script cant send message after question 'what do you do?'. Why? whats problem in code?

```
import telebot

bot = telebot.TeleBot('API')


@bot.message_handler(commands=['tarot'])
def start_message(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Hello!')

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def send_text(message):
    if message.text.lower() == 'hi tarot':
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Hi!  ' + message.chat.first_name + '!')
        @bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
        def send2_text(message2):
            if message2.text.lower() == 'what do you do?':
                bot.send_message(message2.chat.id, 'im learning mode?  ' + message2.chat.first_name + '!')

    elif message.text.lower() == 'By':
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'BY!  ' + message.chat.first_name + '!')

bot.polling()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want, to allow asking what do you do only if user send hi to bot at any time

```
import telebot

bot = telebot.TeleBot('API')
hi_ids = []


@bot.message_handler(commands=['tarot'])
def start_message(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Hello!')


# content_types=['text'] is not required as it default type
@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: message.text.lower() == 'hi tarot')
def send_hi(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f'Hi! {message.chat.first_name}!')
    if message.chat.id not in hi_ids:
        hi_ids.append(message.chat.id)


@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: message.text.lower() == 'what do you do?' and message.chat.id in hi_ids)
def send2_text(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f'I\'m learning mode? {message.chat.first_name}!')


@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: message.text.lower() == 'by')
def good_buy(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f'BY! {message.chat.first_name}!')


bot.infinity_polling(3600, True)  # One hour and ignore net errors
```

But if you want to allow user to ask what bot is doing right after hi use this code

```
import telebot

bot = telebot.TeleBot('API')


def second_question(message):
    if message.text is None:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Nice none text message")
    elif message.text.lower() == 'what do you do?':
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f'I\'m learning mode? {message.chat.first_name}!')
    elif message.text.lower() == 'do you like cats?':
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Sure')


@bot.message_handler(commands=['tarot'])
def start_message(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Hello!')


# content_types=['text'] is not required as it default type
@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: message.text.lower() == 'hi tarot')
def send_hi(message):
    bot.register_next_step_handler(bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f'Hi! {message.chat.first_name}!'),
                                   second_question)


@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: message.text.lower() == 'by')
def good_buy(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f'BY! {message.chat.first_name}!')


bot.infinity_polling(3600, True)  # One hour and ignore net errors
```